# This query works on MySQL but don't work on MS Access because of the syntax,Why?

Tags: java, ms-access

After I get the content of `dump`, there was a `CREATE TABLE` query, but this query didn't work on MS Access because of `Syntax error`.

Here is the orignal query from the `dump` file( that works on both Sqlite and MySQL):

```
 String query ="CREATE TABLE PATIENT("
       + "  ID varchar(45) NOT NULL,"
       + "  NAME varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,"
       + "  COUNT int(11) DEFAULT NULL,"
       + "  PRIMARY KEY (ID)"
       + ")";
```

After removing `DEFAULT NULL` and changing `int(11)` to `integer` it executed.

I could find this problem, but in future, shall I expect more problems?

Comment: Yes. Expect a lot of problems using MS Access. Just don't do it to be honest. MS Access is not fit for purpose with so many alteratives. High on the list is a lack of decent concurrency support, file locks, poor SQL support, peculiar bugs and general shitness.

Comment: Actually, it's the exact question that I asked as @anakata mentioned.

Comment: @PaulSullivan: thanks, It was just a matter of interest to see what happen, I am actually not using MS Access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are porting to different backend environments you should always be aware of supported data types.  [Here is what access supports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and also here is [more info on the create table syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177893%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for access.  And yes, porting from MySQL you likely will hit more problems like this.

Also note the documentation states (just in case you decide to only use Access as the front end).

> The Microsoft Access database engine does not support the use of
>   CREATE TABLE, or any of the DDL statements, with non-Microsoft Access
>   database engine databases. Use the DAO Create methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` is a SQL reserved keyword; it's used as a function to determine the number of rows that match a query.  MySQL and Sqlite are being lenient and letting you use it as the name of a column since they can distinguish whether you're using it as a column name or a function name, but it's technically incorrect.  Change the column name.

Additionally, Access's data types don't quite match standard SQL; the link provided in the earlier answer should be helpful.  You probably need to define the column as a LONG to match the size you're wanting.

Comment: You can use square brackets [COUNT] in order to use a reserved keyword or, better, rename the field. (NAME is also reserved in Access, but not in the SQL.)